# How to check whether my custom hashing is good in hash_map?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stl, hash, hashmap

I've written a custom hashing for my custom key in stdext::hash_map and would like to check whether the hasher is good. I'm using STL supplied with VS 2008. A typical check, as I know, is to check the uniformity of distribution among buckets.

How should I organize such a check correctly? A solution that comes to my mind is to modify STL sources to add a method to hash_map that walks through buckets and does the subject. Is there are any better ways?

Maybe, derive from hash_map and create there such method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd run one (large) dataset through stl::hash_map. Once done, I'd collect the results for all buckets using the following method

From `hash_map`:

```
size_type elems_in_bucket (size_type __n) const;
```

Finally, I would do compute the **standard deviation (SD)** of the **elem-to-bucket distribution**.

I'd do the above for different hash functions. Whichever hash function results in minimum SD is the winner (for this dataset).

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect, but I don't have this members out of the box. SHould I define _HAS_TRADITIONAL_STL? Which side effects would it cause?

Comment: I've found :) In my compiler's STL (MS VS 2008) this method is called `bucket_size`. Great thanks!

Comment: @flashnik: You are welcome. Feel free to comment back if you have any follow-up question.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet might be to just take your hashing algorithm to an array of ints and count the number of times that each hash bucket is hit, given real-world data.  (I'm suggesting taking the STL out of the equation here, really.)

If you end up seeing high deviation in your counts with large sets of real-world data, your hashing algorithm is generating lots of collisions when there are plenty of empty (or emptier) buckets available.

Note that 'high deviation' is a relative term.  A good hash algorithm is a deterministic random process and any random process has a chance of generating strange results, so test often, test well, and wherever possible, use your actual problem domain as a source of your tests and your controls.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm going to do. But AFAIK I can't access buckets (and amount of items in them) outside of hash_map. Now I see two ways: modify STL sources or derive own class from hash_map with an appropriate method. I'd prefer the second solution. Are there any other ways?

Comment: ...which is why user30997 says in the firts paragraph to take STL out of the picture and just run your hash method over real data and incrementing counters.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid different STL realisations can work with hash results differently. For example, using `this->comp(_Keyval) & _Mask` to determine a busket works correctly iff _Mask is `2^N -1`. And _Mask is determined by hasher functor (it is a multiplication of min_buckets supplied by hasher). In any other cases it is not equivalent to taking a reminder `this->comp(_Keyval) % _Mask`.